# How to display the responded message at the left handside and replied messages at the right hand side by fetching using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to reactjs.

I want to display the reponded message at the left hand side if the condition "***isrespond: true***" otherwise the message need to get displayed at the right hand side (like a list of messages need to display only. I don't know how to write the condition for it.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    fetch('api/messagelist')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({ message: data })
    })
    .catch(console.log)
  }
```

this would be jsondata in api:

```
{
"message": "Hello everyone",
    "isrespond": true,
},

{
"message": "hi",
    "isrespond": false,

}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, each of your message object should have a unique id, so that React knows what to update and when.

[You should never use an index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)

I would also recommend you to have an array containing each of your messages, such as :

```
messages = [{
    "id": 1,
    "message": "Hello everyone",
    "isrespond": true,
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "message": "hi",

}]
```

as it will be easier to handle. (You can only include "isrespond" only if it's true)

Then you can render

```
<div>
    {
        messages.map(message => {
            return (<p key={message.id} className={message.isrespond ? "isrespond" : ""}>{message.message}</p>)
        })
    }
</div>
```

And css

```
.isrepond {
   margin-left: auto;
   //Whatever CSS you need to make it go right
}
```

For each messages, you'll render one "line". This "line" has a key, and a className that is "isrespond" only if the message.isrespond is present.

Comment: We have "isrespond: false" in our api link.. so that is the issue i'm facing.

Comment: It won't change anything then. You message will have "isrepond" class (or whatever you want as a classname) and otherwise the other "".

isrepond could be "float: right" in your css

Comment: I want to change the right hand side message background color without inline styling.. Could you help me in this?

Comment: In my answer `isrespond` would indicate the class `isrepond`. You can simply apply the CSS you wish on this class in your CSS file. For example : `.isrespond {background-color: red;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes, one for left and other one for right alignment.

```
this.state.message.forEach((element, index)=>{
<div key={index} className={(element.isrespond? 'className1' : 'className2')}>
})
```

this above code should be placed where you are trying to render the messages.

Comment: Could you tell me with an example? I mean in briefly

Comment: You should never use index as a key, it has danger in terms of rendering for React

Comment: @Victor Jozwicki -  i applied this "<div floated={ element.isrespond ? "right" : "left"}> {result.message}</div>" it came but how to change colour of the message when it is right aligned? Could you please help me in this?

Comment: This is simply a css class ... so you can change the color by using ... color